# Getting variable value from $.each anonymous function

Tags: ajax, jquery, scope

This is my AJAX success callback:

```
success: function(data){
        var uD = '<ul class="user-details">';
        $.each(data['user details'], (function(key,val){
            uD += '<li><label>' + key + ':</label><span>' + val + '</span></li>';
        });
        uD += '</ul>';
        return uD;
}
```

data is a JSON object.

As you can see, I'm trying to build a list out of the JSON object, but by the time I return the variable `uD`, it's undefined. How can I get the value of `uD` past the scope of the $.each function?

Edit: Sorry, I should have specified. The return statement was only in the AJAX callback because the AJAX call is within another function (which needs to return something.) Since it's async, I couldn't return 'after' the AJAX call, it had to be in the callback.

Comment: It is not a problem of `$.each`, you cannot return data from an Ajax callback. See: [jQuery: Return data after ajax call success](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success) (voted to be closed as duplicate)

Comment: @Kelly: There is no `return` in the `each` callback. The data is appended to the `uD` variable which the callback has access to. This will work correctly. But the OP is returning the data from the `success` callback and this will not work.

Comment: seems the question was flawed, according to wanavak's comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an Ajax callback, you cannot return data. I guess you want to insert the `UL` you have built into the DOM, so you should do it inside your Ajax callback function.

```
success: function(data){
        var uD = '<ul class="user-details">';
        $.each(data['user details'], (function(key,val){
            uD += '<li><label>' + key + ':</label><span>' + val + '</span></li>';
        });
        uD += '</ul>';
        $('body').append(uD);
}
```

Instead of `body` specify the element you want to insert it into or use any other DOM Insertion functions.

With asynchronous AJAX calls you cannot really `return` things. So you cannot do things like

```
function GetMyList() {
     //AJAX CALL
     //RETURN RESULT OF AJAX CALL
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. The return statement was only in the AJAX callback because the AJAX call is within another function (which needs to return something.) Since it's async, I couldn't return 'after' the AJAX call, it had to be in the callback.

Comment: @wanovak Because it's `async` you cannot really know when will it actually return, so you cannot depend on it in your `another function` that has made the AJAX call. You can make your AJAX callback call another function though, or trigger an event.

Comment: Technically this was correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a variable *before* your AJAX call and set a value to it *inside* the `success` function, you will be able to read it variable on any other part of you code.

**EDIT**

Based on your comment (you need to return this value from a function), all your calls to this function needs wait it response. Then, I suggest you to turn off `async` .

```
var uD = null;

...

async: false,
success: function(data){
    uD = '<ul class="user-details">';
    $.each(data['user details'], (function(key,val){
        uD += '<li><label>' + key + ':</label><span>' + val + '</span></li>';
    });
    uD += '</ul>';
}

return uD;
```